# How do I getElementsByClassName instead of getElementById here?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace the following's code of simple countdown timer getElementById('countdown') with getElementsByClassName('timer') instead but the code gets broken. Any idea?

```js
var seconds = 60;
function secondPassed() {
  var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
  if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
  }
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
  if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

```html
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
```

Comment: Here is a demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/kg6q01ny/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can use document.getElementsByClassName("timer")[0] instead of getElementById('countdown').

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName() will always return an array, rather than an element directly.

Comment: Do you mean it is not recommended to be used? sorry I am beginner to JS..

Comment: You can use any format that you want if it can achieve the target. :)